# Parsing the Javascript content

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I have the javascript code as a text, after parsing from the html file, and I want to get the "CurrencyCode":"EUR" out of those strings, especially the EUR value, so which way can I achieve it? Regex ? Thank you

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#book-simple').prepend('<div id="spinnerContainer" style="color: #224477;margin:5px 0 15px;text-align:center;"><img src="/img/spinner2.gif" />&nbsp;Cargando pol&iacute;ticas...</div>')
    $.post(
        'bridgeT.php', {
            f: 'policies',
            h: '010',
            d: '[{"RatePlanID":"BAR","RatePlanCode":"BAR-SA","RatePlanType":"BAR","RoomTypeCode":"WSTD","ExpireDate":"2014-03-22","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","sources":[{"RateSource":"BAR","ExpireDate":"2014-03-21","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","AmountAfterTax":"230.0","AmountBeforeTax":"230.0","CurrencyCode":"EUR","Discount":null}]},{"RatePlanID":"388","RatePlanCode":"388-SA","RatePlanType":"OFE","RoomTypeCode":"WSTD","ExpireDate":"2014-03-22","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","sources":[{"RateSource":"BAR","ExpireDate":"2014-03-21","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","AmountAfterTax":"230.0","AmountBeforeTax":"230.0","CurrencyCode":"EUR","Discount":{"Type":"DTO","Percent":"10.0"}}]},{"RatePlanID":"BAR","RatePlanCode":"BAR-SA","Discount":null}]}]',
            l: 'fr_FR'
        }, function(d) {

string content = html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
```

This content variable has the javascript code inside, now I wish to use Regex to get the CurrencyCode: EUR

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you saying you have scraped the above from an HTML page, and want to search it, as a block of text, for the CurrencyCode? What language are you using to do this parsing?

Comment: @ChrisBallard : I have those javascript text after parsing from the html file, and now as a text, I wish to get the CurrencyCode:EUR out of the javascript text in the html file Thanks

Comment: Still using javascript to do that? or another language?

Comment: I want to use Regex to get the CurrencyCode:EUR from the plein string value, string content = html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml . this content variable has the javascript code inside @ChrisBallard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a valid JSON String.

I don't know how you ended up with this data but it is likely by looping through the name and value of input fields or something like that... Anyways.

The best way for you to do this in Javascript is to make that String that is actually the value of the 'd' key in you object a valid JSON String and then you just have to get the appropriate element.

To make it a valid JSON String you actually only have to remove the two last characters '}]' since they do not match anything in the String.

To make this, the best way is to fix the code that produces this String but if you can't here is a simple but ugly way :

```
var incorrectString = '[{"RatePlanID":"BAR","RatePlanCode":"BAR-SA","RatePlanType":"BAR","RoomTypeCode":"WSTD","ExpireDate":"2014-03-22","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","sources":[{"RateSource":"BAR","ExpireDate":"2014-03-21","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","AmountAfterTax":"230.0","AmountBeforeTax":"230.0","CurrencyCode":"EUR","Discount":null}]},{"RatePlanID":"388","RatePlanCode":"388-SA","RatePlanType":"OFE","RoomTypeCode":"WSTD","ExpireDate":"2014-03-22","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","sources":[{"RateSource":"BAR","ExpireDate":"2014-03-21","EffectiveDate":"2014-03-21","AmountAfterTax":"230.0","AmountBeforeTax":"230.0","CurrencyCode":"EUR","Discount":{"Type":"DTO","Percent":"10.0"}}]},{"RatePlanID":"BAR","RatePlanCode":"BAR-SA","Discount":null}]}]'

var correctedString = incorrectString.substring(0, incorrectString.length - 2);
```

Then it is trivial :

```
var rateObject = JSON.parse(correctedString)

var CurrencyCode = rateObject[0].sources[0].CurrencyCode
```

The way that all this is built makes me feel like reading a bit on Javascript and JSON would be a good thing for you. See [Javascript Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) and [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)